# Different number of decimals for prices and totals

Tags: 7, commerce

I use [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and I have a problem with the number of decimals in prices. In Spain (and I suppose in other countries too), I could have prices of products with more than two decimals, but at the end, the totals are rounded to two decimals. With [currency settings module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_currency_settings) I can set the number of decimals, but It is for all (prices and totals). Is there anyway I could have four decimals for prices and two for totals?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the number of decimal places site wide... I would set it to most precision I am likely to need and shorten it through the theme/js in the places where I need it shorter.  It may not be as graceful as variable precision, but if no other answers come up, it will get the job done...

Comment: Thanks for your comment but It can't be done as you say. For example, if I set decimals to four, then taxs and totals will be internaly rounded to four decimals that is wrong.

Comment: Have you explored https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_decimals_formatter ?

Comment: Yes, but It's the same. This module let you change the display but not the process of rounding. Internaly, It will continue doing calculations using two decimals.

Comment: commerce.currency.inc

'decimals' => 3,   <-- or whatever number of decimal places you need... 

You may have to set up different currencies to vary the precision

Comment: Thanks, but It's the same. I can put it whatever number of decimals I need, but I doesn't solve the problem. For example, I have a product wich costs is 0,0233 €. I need 4 decimals price, but totals in Euros are with 2 decimals.